# Etymology of 策, 朿

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, glyph-origin

What is the etymology of 策 and 朿 ?

As per dictionary the meanings are as below:

朿 cì stab

策 cè policy, plan, scheme, bamboo slip for writing(old), to whip (a horse), to encourage, upward horizontal stroke in calligraphy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

朿 means "thorns". From [说文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)：[朿，木芒也](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%9C%BF)。

Its variant character 刺 is more widely used in modern Chinese.

More ancient usages of inscriptions on bones or tortoise shells of the Shang Dynasty of 朿 is "to stab (ritual animal sacrifices) to death" as in 「朿豕」、「朿羊」、「朿魚」etc, according to [甲骨文合集](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E7%94%B2%E9%AA%A8%E6%96%87%E5%90%88%E9%9B%86).

策 means “horse whips” in ancient times, which was usually made of bamboos, some of which have **thorns** at the front end.

[image: 秦始皇陵铜车马马策]

Another hypothesis is 策 evolves from the riding command 敕 which meant to drive the horse. 说文解字: [以策擊馬曰敇](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E7%AD%96)。

Comment: Mou, Felix Zhang Thank you very much for the pictures and detailed explanation. It will help in remembering the meaning of both the characters. Thanks

Comment: @user27485 If you think this answers your question, you should click the "accept" button to mark it as the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the etymologies for both characters:

**策**

*Outlier*

> **FORM**
> 策 cè is composed of 朿 cì and  “bamboo,” which points to the original meaning “a bamboo horsewhip.” 朿 gives the sound.
>
> **COMPONENTS**
>
> In 策,  “bamboo” is a meaning component, pointing to the original meaning “a bamboo horse-whip.”
>
> 朿
> In 策 cè, 朿 cì is a sound component.
>
> **MEANINGS**
> cè
> 1 (orig.) bamboo horsewhip
> 2 → to whip
> 3 ⇒ to encourage
> 4 → walking stick
> 5 ⇒ to support
> 6 → bamboo book
> 7 ⇒ plan

**朿**

*Outlier*

> **FORM**
> Ancient form:
> [image]
> 朿 depicts a three-pointed spear, indicating its original meaning “three-pointed spear.”
>
> **MEANINGS**
> cì
> 1 (orig.) a three-pointed spear
> 2 → sharp; pointy

- 朿 is just a sound component in 策 and shares no semantic meanings

Comment: With 朿, the 3 pointed spear what can be stabbed mainly? Why 3 point spear only for stabbing?